# Builds on RTFD.io: Latest passes, stable fails

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Whenever documentation should get updated on RTFD.io, two builds are built: stable and latest.

For weeks now, [my](https://readthedocs.org/projects/scopus/builds/)  latest builds without problem, but the stable does not how.

How can my stable fail while my latest builds?

The error that occurs is an `ImportError: No module named _tkinter` related to the fact that I load `matplotlib`.  I am also uncertain why there is this error because I use a mock import for exactly this module specified in my config: `autodoc_mock_imports = ["_tkinter"]`.

Comment: To those how vote for close: I came here because read-the-docs wants people to ask questions on SO, see http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/support.html

Comment: I just used the RTD UI to [build the stable version](https://readthedocs.org/projects/scopus/builds/) of your docs successfully. I think RTD caches some packages that it downloaded and installed previously, but I'm not certain, which could cause a failure.

Comment: Again, visit the link, and look at the build logs to see which versions of packages get installed, then audit the logs for each build. When a docs build fails for no apparent logical reason on RTD, it's always a good idea to wipe and rebuild. See http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#deleting-a-stale-or-broken-build-environment for a quick reason and http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builds.html for details of the build process.